# Abrir imagen en JFileChooser y copiarla en JLabel

Tags: java, java-swing, jfilechooser

Deseo abrir el **JFileChooser** y al escoger una imagen se copie a un `jLabel`.

¿Por qué me deja abrir el buscador de ficheros y elegir la imagen pero no la copia en el `jLabel`?

**Código:**

```
private void button_fotoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog(label_foto);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Buscar imagen...");

    if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(seleccion));
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías de incluir tu mensaje de error exactamente como te aparece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION` no es un archivo ni una imágen.

Por ello remplaza

```
label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(seleccion));
```

por

```
File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
Image i = new ImageIcon(f.toURI().toURL());
label_foto.setIcon(i);
```

Como verás en este código:

1. Obtenemos el archivo seleccionado
2. convertimos nuestro archivo en una URL
3. Usamos el constructor de [ImageIcon que recibe una URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.net.URL-).

Comment: Mismo error me aparece.

Comment: intenta de nuevo :)